# How to call wso2 IS web service when using SAML2 SSO authentication

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am trying to call the WSO2 IS web service (i.e: getUserProfile) from service provider when we are using SAML2 SSO authentication ,but i am getting un authorized access.

Do we get any token that can be used to call the web service after the initial authentication,without passing the credential or cookies ??

Comment: We can give you a better answer if you can provide a log or error message given in response.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a permission problem. Make sure you have enable login permission for particular user.

Admin services are secured using common types of security protocols such as HTTP basic authentication, [WS-Security username token](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS400/Security+Token+Service+with+WSO2+Identity+Server), and [session based authentication](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS500/Calling+Admin+Services).

Answer (score 0):

You can use SAML2SSOAuthenticationService.
Please refer the sample [How to get a session cookie from a webapp which uses SAML SSO](http://firzhanblogger.blogspot.sg/2014/12/how-to-get-session-cookie-from-webapp.html)